# How to fail a task after it has run? Aka how to ignoreFailures but repeat the task on the next run?

Tags: gradle

gradle cannot run both JUnit and TestNG tests in the same test task.

So my idea was to create a second test task for TestNG, configure both test tasks with "ignoreFailures true" and have a separate task that generates a single test report for both tasks. Finally a test listener checks for test failures and lets the build fail if needed.

Unfortunately that way when a test is failing the build will fail only the first time around. On the second invocation (of "gradlew build"), the build is incorrectly considered successful. I guess that's because the ignoreFailures makes gradle consider the test task to always be successful and since no input or output changed it does not run the tests again.

Is there a way to tell gradle to continue after test failures, but still re-run the task the next time? So for example mark the task as dirty programmatically?

Or, put another way: Can I have the same effect as the "--continue" command line argument, but right in the build setup and only for specific tasks?

Any other idea for a solution? Can I somehow use/add local task state for that?

Example code is at https://github.com/eekboom/gradle-dual-tests

Comment: I made it work using “finalizedBy” (instead of “ignoreFailures” and “dependsOn”) to chain the “test”, “testNg”, and “testReport” tasks.

See updated code at https://github.com/eekboom/gradle-dual-tests 
Comments/alternative solutions are very welcome.
Feels a bit strange to use "finalizedBy" to chain tasks this way.

Comment: I've looked at it and it seems to be ok. For now, no idea if it can be done better or in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems for now "finalizedBy" is indeed the only way to achieve this:

Consider this

```
task a {
    finalizedBy 'b'
}
task b { ... }
```

Currently (gradle 4.10.2) task "b" is always executed if "a" is in the task graph, regardless of "a" being up-to-date or having done work. This is contrary to the gradle documentation, see also the discussion at the gradle forum: [finalizedBy tasks runs even though the original task is UP-TO-DATE](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/finalizedby-tasks-runs-even-though-the-original-task-is-up-to-date/29150/5)

If you want task "b" to only execute if "a" did some work, you have to make that explicit for example this way

```
task b {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { a.state.upToDate }
}
```

In other words, you can understand "finalizedBy" not so much as "specifies a task that finalizes the work done by this task" (corresponding to "finally" clause in Java) but rather as a way to reconfigure the task graph "to always run the specified task b if this task a is also run and to always run b after a". (In contrast "b.mustRunAfter a" only specifies the ordering, but does not run b if b itself is not on the task graph anyway.)

So for this use case of running both JUnit and TestNG tests and creating a unified test report you can basically do this:

```
// Configure the default task that runs JUnit
test {
   finalizedBy 'testNG'
}
// Create another test task that runs the TestNG tests
task testNg(type: Test) {
    useTestNG()
    finalizedBy 'testReport'
}
// Create a consolidated test report of both JUnit and TestNG tests
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    // This does *not* work:
    //    reportOn test, testNg
    // I guess that's because the testNg task was only executed as part of the "finalizedBy" mechanism
    // (and not because of any "dependsOn"). So use "testResultDirs" instead:
    testResultDirs = files("$buildDir/test-results/test/binary", "$buildDir/test-results/testNg/binary")
}
```

Note that both the "finalizedBy" feature and the "TestReport" task are currently [incubating](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/feature_lifecycle.html)

Complete example is at https://github.com/eekboom/gradle-dual-tests